# Unable to initiate REISUB sequence on E490 Thinkpad

Tags: laptop, keyboard-shortcuts, reboot, lenovo-laptop, thinkpad

The E490 Lenovo Thinkpad has no SysRq key. I have found similar posts describing other ways to initiate SysRq button. So far, I have tried these suggested combinations (all while holding left Alt key):

- Fn + S
- Fn + PrtSc
- Ctrl + Fn + S
- Ctrl + Fn + PrtSc

but none of them showed any reaction when pressing down the REISUB sequence (all while still holding left Alt key).
button

*Note that I also have a BIOS key swap for Crtl and Fn key on this laptop.*

I am not sure what else shall I try to initiate the REISUB sequence correctly.

OS information:

```
cat /proc/version
```

Linux version 4.19.119-1-MANJARO (gcc version 9.3.0 (Arch Linux 9.3.0-1))

Comment: Does Fn+S work without the Bios key swap? This is the documented sequence according to [Keyboard shortcut for Break, Pause, ScrLK, SysRq function on ThinkPad 6 rows Precision keyboard - ThinkPad - GB](https://support.lenovo.com/gb/en/solutions/ht074004)

Comment: The right key combo seems to be Alt - PrtScreen, as stated here (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key), which supposes your keyboard is in QWERTY mode to press the right keys. You can use REISUO to shutdown your PC instead of rebooting it, but Alt-PrntScreen should work.

Comment: I have disabled the Ctrl-Fn swap in BIOS. Now my Alt+Fn+S takes a screenshot and my Alt+PrtScr does nothing (does not initiate any magic commands). I have also added my OS version to the question describtion. Could this somehow be a faulty hardware (I am not aware of what happens under the hood to initiate the SysRq stuff)?